# Comparing two text cells in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, compare

I'm trying to compare two text cells (like `abcDEF`) from different sheets. One sheet is fixed but the other is not.

My code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, n As Long
Dim Project As String
Dim Responsible As String, Site As String, Sample As String, _
    Description As String, Parameter As String, Method As String
Dim j As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

' Find LastRow in Col A into the Sheet2
LastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' Select all Col A in Project
For Each Value In Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
   Project = Project & "," & Value
Next Value

Sheet1.Range("A2").ClearContents: Sheet1.Range("A2").Validation.Delete

' Create the Data Validation List
With Range("A2").Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween,     Formula1:=Project
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

' Select the sheet coinciding with the cell "A2" value
For j = 3 To Sheets.Count

    If Sheets(j).Range("A2").Text = Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text Then
        'Write 4 in sheet1 cell C6 when the two values are coinciding.
        Sheet1.Range("C6") = 4
    End If

Next j
End Sub
```

The problem is the `If...` line, probably is the range definition. I've tried `.Text` and `.Value` and neither works.

Comment: Where is this saved in the VBA Project structure?  It should be saved in each sheet for which you want to handle the change event.  Also, you don't need the loop, and the If statement condition should be `Range("A2").Text = Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text`

Comment: So the code throws an error (which and where?) or the condition never evaluates to True?

Comment: @MarkM I've this only in Sheet1. I've tryed what you say and it's not working.

Comment: @PaulB. I can compile perfectly the code. The problem is the condition as you say.

Comment: Try toggling `EnableEvents` as I mention in my answer and see if that works.

Comment: If you save (sorry for the unformatted code): `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) MsgBox "HI" End Sub` in the "SheetX (SheetX)" object that you are trying to catch the change event for, do you see the dialog box pop-up?  Also, just to make sure I understand - Sheet1 is the editable sheet and Sheet2 is the fixed sheet?

Comment: Exactly I have the code on Sheet1. I have a validation data list on the cell A2 into the sheet1. This list is referring on the sheet2 and it depends on the value in that cell, I want to pick other information from sheets3, 4, 5, ... if cells A2 in both sheet are the same text.

Answer (score 1):

What you may want to use is

```
If StrComp(Sheets(j).Range("A2").Value2, Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value2, _
    vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
'added the underscore since I made it two lines for neatness
```

`vbTextCompare` is case-insensitive, `vbBinaryCompare` is case-sensitive. There are several resources online about [string comparison](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt.html#comp) that can help you.

Also, I noticed you're using `Worksheet_Change` and changing the value of a cell on `Sheet1`. My guess is that your `Worksheet_Change` is for `Sheet1`, yes? If that's the case, then every time you modify `Sheet1`, the sub gets called again (and again and again... until it crashes). To prevent that, you want to add

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

to the start of the sub, then

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

at the end. This way any changes you make to the worksheet won't trigger the `Worksheet_Change` sub.

Comment: I've tryed what you say. But it's still not working... Before the for I've a validation data list in cell "A2" on sheet1. When I check this I want to compare that cell with the other "A2" cells from Sheet3 to the rest of sheets, and when it's true then in other cells in sheet1 have to appear other validation data list depending of the sheet. All code is working but I still have problems with the If... that it's never come true.

Comment: I completed a little bit the code with the previous step to the loop. Maybe there's another error that I can't see, but what I see is the condition never comes true. Without that, the rest is working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: At the end of your code (before the end of the sub) you need to enable events again (`Application.EnableEvents = True`). Also, since you had them deactivated, an easy way to reactivate them is to make a little sub/macro with only this line: `Application.EnableEvents = True`. After that, your `Worksheet_Change` should successfully fire again (your current code means it only runs after the first change, then stops since events are disabled). Your code seems to work fine for me when I copied it into a new workbook. Just be sure that you enable events like I said.

Comment: Just to be clear, make a new Sub (e.g. `Private Sub ReEnable()`), add the line that enables events, then run that macro once (F5 or press the button in the editor). Simply pressing the 'Reset' button will not enable events once they've been disabled.

Comment: I tryed to add the Application.EnableEvents = True at the end of the sub. But then, when I select the options on the list they don't rest on the cell. Also, if I add a new Sub at the end of the actual sub, it's not working.

Comment: Are you sure? Try closing, then opening your workbook again. As far as the validation options, if you enter a bunch of them on Sheet2 (A2:LastRow), then they won't show up on Sheet1 until you make a change to Sheet1 (since the `Worksheet_Change` is where you apply the validation).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11958/discussion-between-zairja-and-meikse)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `EXACT(text1,text2)` function