# Compare two sheets and change value

Tags: vba, compare

I need to compare a sheet (which has 4k date) with another sheet and say 'yes' or 'no'.tried to use

ifSheets(j).Range("A2").Text = Sheets(1).Range("A2").Text Then
        'Write 4 in sheet1 cell C6 when the two values are coinciding.
        Sheet1.Range("C6") = 4
from site,
 [Comparing two text cells in different sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817799/comparing-two-text-cells-in-different-sheets)
but couldn't succeed. tried for 4 days without success so finally thought to ask help

what i try to do is compare sheet 1 range A with a specific value/text in "B2" on sheet 2, sheet 1 range A has about 4k data. if it finds a match I need "B3" to show "Y", if it doesn't find a match "N".
idea is simple but I really need help please...

Answer (score 0):

```
sub main
dim i as integer
for i = 1 to 4000
    if sheet1.cells(i, 1) = sheet2.cells(2, 2) then 
        sheet2.cells(3,2 ) = "Y"
        exit sub
    end if
next i

sheet2.cells(3, 2) = "N"
end sub
```

Comment: amazing,could you modify it to compare sheet1 A1 data with sheet2 B2 to say BBZ? this is what I needed at the first place. i thought I can modify but couldn't so far. (basically it is like compare sheet1 A1 vertical data with sheet2 row2 data horizontally and say Y/N in the below row.) Appreciate your help

Comment: first you have to figure out what index the column BBZ is. then change the number 2 to that index. To figure out the index go to options>>Forumulas>> check R1C1.

Comment: Thanks, please help me to modify this way: compare values in sheet1 A1 values with B2 and if it finds Y, if it doesn't N. And continue comparing sheet1 A1 values with sheet2 C2,D2 upto GR2 and say Y/N below respective cells like B3,C3.....GR3. Values in B2 to GR2 are cell specifics.

Comment: I believe I've answered your question as to how this could be achieved. If you require further assistance in your project you could refer to my profile